# What is another word to describe the way an author creates a visual image in our mind? (hard)

Tags: word-choice

For example, we can say "Through a simile of grotesque, the author...

> visually ignites
>
> conjures an image
>
> creates an atmosphere comparable in ambience

etc

I am looking for phrases that I can use to describe the way an author creates visual imagery :). I found this abit harder than I expected.

Ta,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's writing advice

Comment: I'm anxious to see if someone has a good answer for this.  My husband and I have an ongoing battle over which classical music to clean the house to.  He likes German composers; but I prefer Russian - because the music is more visually evocative to me. (I like to visit other places while my hands are in the sink.)

Comment: " Through a similie of grotesque, the author paints a picture"

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is not 'writing advice'. I am looking to fill my vocab with new phrases, as to not be repetitive.

Comment: @Oldbag I am not sure?

Comment: @youknowwhoiam: It sure looks like writing advice to me. On which topic, note that *through a simile of grotesque* is a non-standard usage. You can do something *through/using a/the simile of [**something** serving as a simile]*, but *grotesque* is normally an adjective, so it needs an appropriate noun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok thank you for that correction. Can you please elaborate how you perceive this to be writing advice? What do you define to be 'writing advice'? I am merely asking for phrases to add to my word bank, to which I can utilise at will during essays. Thinking about this issue further, 'writing advice' is a very broad term.

Comment: @youknowwhoiam: The problem is there's no single unambiguously "correct" answer for your question. A dozen different competent writers would probably come up with a dozen different ways of expressing it. And there's no particular reason why you can't use one of your three suggestions (four, if you count *creates visual imagery*, which you used quite naturally to encapsulate what you mean). It's effectively an open-ended "beauty contest" question.

Comment: Do not vandalise content. If you want to delete the question, register your account: this will enable you do so (provided no-one upvotes an answer).

Answer (score 2):

Clearly *[evoke](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/evoke)* stands out:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]   1 Bring or recall (a feeling, memory, or image) to the
>   conscious mind:

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure whether you’re looking for a single word (as stated in the question) or a phrase (as stated in the post).

In the first case:

> **to depict** – to represent by **or as if by a picture**

(Merriam Webster on-line dictionary definition)